# Split comma separated values based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to split comma separated values based on another table

I cannot normalize it since original table has over 8 million rows. It crushed my laptop when I tried it.

How can I put data into relevant columns and create a new column if data is not found.

For example:

TableA,

```
Type1        Type2
---------------------
 A            F         
 B            G
 C            H
 D            I
 E           NULL
```

TableB

```
ID     Country     AllTypes            
---------------------------------
1       Italy      A, B, C
2       USA        D, E, A, F   
4       Japan      I, O, Z        
5       UK         NULL
```

By using these two tables, I would like to get the output such as

```
ID     Country     AllTypes          Type1        Type2    UnCaptured            
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       Italy      A, B, C           A, B, C       NULL     NULL
2       USA        D, E, G, F        D, E          G, F     NULL
4       Japan      I, O, Z           NULL          I        O, Z
5       UK         NULL              NULL          NULL     NULL
```

This is I have done so far

```
with TableA as (
  select 'A' as Type1, 'F' as Type2 union all
  select 'B', 'G' union all
  select 'C', 'H' union all
  select 'D', 'I' union all
  select 'E', NULL
),
TableB as (
  select 1 as ID, 'Italy' as Country, 'A, B, C' as Alltypes union all
  select 2, 'USA', 'D, E, A, F' union all  
  select 4, 'Japan', 'I', 'O', 'Z' union all
  select 5, 'UK', NULL
)

select b.Id, b.Country, b.Alltypes,
    String_Agg(v.type1,',') Type1,
    String_Agg(v.type2,',') Type2
    **String_Agg(v.Type3,',') Uncaptured*** ------- This query
    
from tableb b
outer apply (
    select Trim(value) t,
        case when exists 
          (select * from tablea a where a.type1=Trim(value)) 
        then Trim(value) end type1,
        case when exists
          (select * from tablea a where a.type2=Trim(value)) 
        then Trim(value) end Type2,
        Case when not exists                                  ------------This query
          ( (select * from tablea a where a.type1=Trim(value)) -------
             and                                               ------
             (select * from tablea a where a.type2=Trim(value))------
          ) then Trim(value) end Type3**                        -------------
    from String_Split(alltypes, ',')
)v
group by Id, Country, AllTypes
```

Without highlighted queries(-----) which are for creating a new column (Uncaptured), it works ok like below.

```
Id  Country Alltypes    Type1   Type2
1   Italy   A, B, C     A,B,C   NULL
2   USA     D, E, A, F  D,E,A   F
4   Japan   I, O, Z     I       NULL
5   UK      NULL        NULL    NULL
```

But if I add those highlighted queries, it shows error. I was also thinking of `else` but did not work as well.

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Isn't it just `Case when not exists (select * from tablea a where a.type1=Trim(value))
and not exists (select * from tablea a where a.type2=Trim(value))
then Trim(value) end Type3`

Comment: I would strongly suggest fixing your design and normalising it.

Comment: Normalizing your design is almost certainly going to perform better than any queries you do on the above design. I'm surprised even an old laptop should be able to munch 8 million rows. Also it doesn't seem to make sense: is the `Type` coming from the `Type1` column or the `Type2` column?

Comment: I would suggest to load required data to the application and do conversation with programming language designed for this ;)

Comment: @DaleK Yes! that is correct. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks all and sorry for the horrible design. I tried to normalise it but my original data has about 15 columns and 2~30 values in Alltypes column. When I tried to normalise it, It shows I cannot do that. It will have over 100 million rows. My trial might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
----------------------- DDL+DML: Should have been provided by the OP !
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TableA,TableB
GO

create table TableA(Type1 CHAR(1), Type2 char(1))
GO
INSERT TableA (Type1,Type2) VALUES
    ('A', 'F'  ),        
    ('B', 'G'  ),
    ('C', 'H'  ),
    ('D', 'I'  ),
    ('E', NULL )
GO

CREATE TABLE TableB (ID INT, Country NVARCHAR(100), AllTypes NVARCHAR(100))
GO
INSERT TableB (ID,Country,AllTypes)VALUES 
(1, 'Italy','A, B, C'     ),
(2, 'USA  ','D, E, G, F'  ),
(4, 'Japan','I, O, Z'     ),
(5, 'UK   ','NULL'        )
GO

----------------------- Solution
;WITH MyCTE AS (
    SELECT ID,Country,AllTypes, MyType = TRIM([value])
    FROM TableB
    CROSS APPLY string_split(AllTypes,',')
)
,MyCTE02 as (
    SELECT ID,Country,AllTypes, MyType,a1.Type1,a2.Type2,
        UnCaptured = CASE WHEN a1.Type1 IS NULL and a2.Type2 IS NULL THEN MyType END
    FROM MyCTE c
    LEFT JOIN TableA a1 ON c.MyType = a1.Type1
    LEFT JOIN TableA a2 ON c.MyType = a2.Type2
)
SELECT ID,Country,AllTypes--,MyType
    ,Type1 = STRING_AGG(Type1,','),Type2 = STRING_AGG(Type2,','),UnCaptured = STRING_AGG(UnCaptured,',')
FROM MyCTE02
GROUP BY ID,Country,AllTypes
GO
```

Comment: By the way, check the result when you add two non-clustered index on TableA, one on column Type1 and the other on column Type2. This will let the server scan the indexes instead of scanning the full table twice and improve the comparting  in the JOIN action.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
outer apply (
    select Trim(value) t, a1.type1, a2.type2,
        CASE WHEN COALESCE(a1.type1, a2.type2) IS NULL THEN Trim(s.value) END unCaptured
    from String_Split(alltypes, ',') s
    left join tablea a1 where a1.type1=Trim(s.value)
    left join tablea a2 where a2.type2=Trim(s.value)
)v
```